# If i buy something on xubuntu software store can i download later across my account?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, software-center

If I buy on Xubuntu software center (laptop) can I use on my Ubuntu desktop? Also will I have to purchase again. (Same account)

Answer (score 1):

No , you do not need to purchase it again. You can restore your purchase with the same account you used to purchase the application.

Comment: Using the same account will it download again?

Comment: @dobby3698 yes it will.